# Configuration of the input capture functionality of PIC18F46K22

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab

I'am using a PIC18F46K22 to measure time that elapses between two event (rising edges of a square wave) using the input capture mode. I configured the related registers but I don't know because the code doesn't work; I'll show you a summary of my code. This is the part of code in the main function that configures the input capture:

```
//IC configuration
    //Input Capture is RC1 (pin 12), TMR1 is used
TRISCbits.RC1 = 1;
CCPTMRS0bits.C2TSEL1 = 0;
CCPTMRS0bits.C2TSEL0 = 0;

PIE2bits.CCP2IE = 1;
PIR2bits.CCP2IF = 0;
    //IC on every rising edge
CCP2CONbits.CCP2M3 = 0;
CCP2CONbits.CCP2M2 = 1;
CCP2CONbits.CCP2M1 = 0;
CCP2CONbits.CCP2M0 = 1;
```

And this is the ISR code:

```
void interrupt ISR(void) {    
    if(PIR2bits.CCP2IF) {
        PIR2bits.CCP2IF = 0;

       //code...
    }    
}
```

What's wrong or missing in the configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: For one, the timer needs to be initialized and run, per section 14.1.2 of the datasheet. There may be other errors as well, get the timer running and come back with results.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a part of the code but there is also the initialization of the timer:
    `// TIMER1 settings
     //FOSC source
    T1CONbits.TMR1CS1 = 0;
    T1CONbits.TMR1CS0 = 1;
        //prescaler 1:1
    T1CONbits.T1CKPS1 = 0;
    T1CONbits.T1CKPS0 = 0;
    T1CONbits.T1RD16 = 1; //enables read/write register in one 16 bit operation
    TMR1 = 0x00;   //Clear contents of the timer1 register
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
`

Comment: This is not readable.

Comment: Resolved! I forgot to set the PEIE and GIE bits! Now it works.